# How to put a delay on AngularJS instant search?

Tags: search, filter, angularjs, timeout, delay

I have a performance issue that I can't seem to address. I have an instant search but it's somewhat laggy, since it starts searching on each `keyup()`.

JS:

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.controller('DisplayController', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('data.json').then(function(result){
    $scope.entries = result.data;
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<input id="searchText" type="search" placeholder="live search..." ng-model="searchText" />
<div class="entry" ng-repeat="entry in entries | filter:searchText">
<span>{{entry.content}}</span>
</div>
```

The JSON data isn't even that large, 300KB only, I think what I need to accomplish is to put a delay of ~1 sec on the search to wait for the user to finish typing, instead of performing the action on each keystroke. AngularJS does this internally, and after reading docs and other topics on here I couldn't find a specific answer.

I would appreciate any pointers on how I can delay the instant search.

Comment: You're getting all json on init app... and then your search filter isn't getting the data second time on typing... it's filtering already existing model. Am I Correct?

Comment: Did the answer below work out? If so, please accept the answer. If not, let me know and I'll further clarify.

Comment: Hey Jason, thanks for the response. I was trying to play around with your code but no luck, search stops working altogether for me.

Comment: Nevermind, it was my bad I overlooked something. Your solution works indeed. Thank you :)

Comment: Take a look at this answer here, which provides a directive that allows you to put a delay on ng-change: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21121460/angular-directive-encapsulating-a-delay-for-ng-change/21420441#21420441

Answer (score 122, accepted):

(See answer below for a Angular 1.3 solution.)

The issue here is that the search will execute every time the model changes, which is every keyup action on an input.

There would be cleaner ways to do this, but probably the easiest way would be to switch the binding so that you have a $scope property defined inside your Controller on which your filter operates. That way you can control how frequently that $scope variable is updated. Something like this:

JS:

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.controller('DisplayController', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $http.get('data.json').then(function(result){
        $scope.entries = result.data;
    });

    // This is what you will bind the filter to
    $scope.filterText = '';

    // Instantiate these variables outside the watch
    var tempFilterText = '',
        filterTextTimeout;
    $scope.$watch('searchText', function (val) {
        if (filterTextTimeout) $timeout.cancel(filterTextTimeout);

        tempFilterText = val;
        filterTextTimeout = $timeout(function() {
            $scope.filterText = tempFilterText;
        }, 250); // delay 250 ms
    })
});
```

HTML:

```
<input id="searchText" type="search" placeholder="live search..." ng-model="searchText" />
<div class="entry" ng-repeat="entry in entries | filter:filterText">
    <span>{{entry.content}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that $scope.$watch on an `ng-model` won't work inside [angular-ui bootstrap's modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)

Comment: I think it will also work without the tempFilterText variable:
    $scope.$watch('searchText', function (val) {
        if (filterTextTimeout) $timeout.cancel(filterTextTimeout);

        filterTextTimeout = $timeout(function() {
            $scope.filterText = val;
        }, 250); // delay 250 ms
    })

Comment: @JosTheeuwen it's then simply a global variable which is considered bad practice and not allowed in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

Answer (score 301):

**UPDATE**

Now it's easier than ever (Angular 1.3), just add a debounce option on the model.

`<input type="text" ng-model="searchStr" ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}">`

Updated plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/4V13gK

Documentation on ngModelOptions:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

**Old method:**

Here's another method with no dependencies beyond angular itself.

You need set a timeout and compare your current string with the past version, if both are the same then it performs the search.

```
$scope.$watch('searchStr', function (tmpStr)
{
  if (!tmpStr || tmpStr.length == 0)
    return 0;
   $timeout(function() {

    // if searchStr is still the same..
    // go ahead and retrieve the data
    if (tmpStr === $scope.searchStr)
    {
      $http.get('//echo.jsontest.com/res/'+ tmpStr).success(function(data) {
        // update the textarea
        $scope.responseData = data.res; 
      });
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

and this goes into your view:

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="searchStr">

<textarea> {{responseData}} </textarea>
```

The mandatory plunker:
http://plnkr.co/dAPmwf

Comment: For me it's much more understandable answer than accepted :) Thanks!

Comment: Isn't there an issue where where multiple model changes could stack up, thus causing duplicate requests? In @JasonAden's answer, he takes care of that by cancelling previously queued events.

Comment: In theory, if the model experiences a change, but the data remains the same, it would cause multiple requests. In practice I've never seen it happen. You can add a flag to check for that edge case if you're worried.

Comment: This is by far the superior choice for angular 1.3

Comment: Warning here: If you have a keypress event that submits or triggers, it will do so without the latest model value since the value binding is debounced. e.g. type 'foo' and on an immediate keypress return the value will still be an empty string.

Comment: I observed, It's depends upon service response time. So assume, If I search 1 and search 100 then search with 1 will return more response and take longer time to return data and  100 will return less response and take lesser time to return data by 1 search. Now I entered 1 in search box and before returning result of 1, I entered 100 in search box. Now Search with 100 returned data and then Search with 1 returned data. So my result table will have latest response which is returned by 1. How to solve this issue?

Comment: @AnandSomani I would suggest upgrading to Angular 1.3 at the least, if not possible the "robust" solution would be to store the promise synchronously and cancel the promise if another search is performed, if it was successful update the model. I feel like my method was pretty much a hack for an essential feature that angular was missing at the time.

Answer (score 33):

In Angular 1.3 I would do this:

HTML:

```
<input ng-model="msg" ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.$watch('variableName', function(nVal, oVal) {
    if (nVal !== oVal) {
        myDebouncedFunction();
    }
});
```

Basically you're telling angular to run `myDebouncedFunction()`, when the the `msg` scope variable changes. The attribute `ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}"` makes sure that `msg` can only update once a second.

Answer (score 10):

```
 <input type="text"
    ng-model ="criteria.searchtext""  
    ng-model-options="{debounce: {'default': 1000, 'blur': 0}}"
    class="form-control" 
    placeholder="Search" >
```

Now we can set ng-model-options debounce with time and when blur, model need to be changed immediately otherwise on save it will have older value if delay is not completed.

Answer (score 9):

For those who uses keyup/keydown in the HTML markup.
This doesn't uses watch.

**JS**

```
app.controller('SearchCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
  var promise = '';
  $scope.search = function() {
    if(promise){
      $timeout.cancel(promise);
    }
    promise = $timeout(function() {
    //ajax call goes here..
    },2000);
  };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="search" autocomplete="off" ng-model="keywords" ng-keyup="search()" placeholder="Search...">
```

Answer (score 6):

Debounced / throttled model updates for angularjs : http://jsfiddle.net/lgersman/vPsGb/3/

In your case there is nothing more to do than using the directive in the jsfiddle code like this:

```
<input 
    id="searchText" 
    type="search" 
    placeholder="live search..." 
    ng-model="searchText" 
    ng-ampere-debounce
/>
```

Its basically a small piece of code consisting of a single angular directive named "ng-ampere-debounce" utilizing http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/ which can be attached to any dom element. The directive reorders the attached event handlers so that it can control when to throttle events.

You can use it for throttling/debouncing
* model angular updates 
* angular event handler ng-[event]
* jquery event handlers

Have a look : http://jsfiddle.net/lgersman/vPsGb/3/

The directive will be part of the Orangevolt Ampere framework (https://github.com/lgersman/jquery.orangevolt-ampere).

Answer (score 6):

#### Just for users redirected here:

As introduced in `Angular 1.3` you can use [ng-model-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) attribute:

```
<input 
       id="searchText" 
       type="search" 
       placeholder="live search..." 
       ng-model="searchText"
       ng-model-options="{ debounce: 250 }"
/>
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe that the best way to solve this problem is by using Ben Alman's plugin [jQuery throttle / debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/). In my opinion there is no need to delay the events of every single field in your form.

Just wrap your $scope.$watch handling function in $.debounce like this:

```
$scope.$watch("searchText", $.debounce(1000, function() {
    console.log($scope.searchText);
}), true);
```

Comment: You'll need to wrap this in a $scope.$apply

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to add a delay functionality to model update. The simple directive seems to do a trick:

```
app.directive('delayedModel', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            model: '=delayedModel'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            element.val(scope.model);

            scope.$watch('model', function(newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal !== oldVal) {
                    element.val(scope.model);        
                }
            });

            var timeout;
            element.on('keyup paste search', function() {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    scope.model = element[0].value;
                    element.val(scope.model);
                    scope.$apply();
                }, attrs.delay || 500);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Usage:

```
<input delayed-model="searchText" data-delay="500" id="searchText" type="search" placeholder="live search..." />
```

So you just use `delayed-model` in place of `ng-model` and define desired `data-delay`.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/OmB4C3jtUD2Wjq5kzTSU?p=preview

Comment: hey! can you explain how `model: '=delayedModel'` is working? Or can you point me to a link where I can find it?

Comment: @AkashAgrawal It's a two way data binding. Read about it here http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile

Comment: @dfsq I was using ng-change and it used to trigger whenever there is a change in the text. But I cannot use it when a directive is defined. `element.on('change')` triggers only on blur. (1) Is there a work around? (2) how to call a function of the controller on text change?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with a directive that basicly what it does is to bind the real ng-model on a special attribute which I watch in the directive, then using a debounce service I update my directive attribute, so the user watch on the variable that he bind to debounce-model instead of ng-model.

```
.directive('debounceDelay', function ($compile, $debounce) {
return {
  replace: false,
  scope: {
    debounceModel: '='
  },
  link: function (scope, element, attr) {
    var delay= attr.debounceDelay;
    var applyFunc = function () {
      scope.debounceModel = scope.model;
    }
    scope.model = scope.debounceModel;
    scope.$watch('model', function(){
      $debounce(applyFunc, delay);
    });
    attr.$set('ngModel', 'model');
    element.removeAttr('debounce-delay'); // so the next $compile won't run it again!

   $compile(element)(scope);
  }
};
});
```

Usage:

```
<input type="text" debounce-delay="1000" debounce-model="search"></input>
```

And in the controller :

```
    $scope.search = "";
    $scope.$watch('search', function (newVal, oldVal) {
      if(newVal === oldVal){
        return;
      }else{ //do something meaningful }
```

**Demo in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6K7Kd/37/**

the $debounce service can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/Warspawn/6K7Kd/

**Inspired by eventuallyBind directive** http://jsfiddle.net/fctZH/12/

Answer (score 0):

Angular 1.3 will have ng-model-options debounce, but until then, you have to use a timer like Josue Ibarra said. However, in his code he launches a timer on every key press. Also, he is using setTimeout, when in Angular one has to use $timeout or use $apply at the end of setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

Why does everyone wants to use watch? You could also use a function:

```
var tempArticleSearchTerm;
$scope.lookupArticle = function (val) {
    tempArticleSearchTerm = val;

    $timeout(function () {
        if (val == tempArticleSearchTerm) {
            //function you want to execute after 250ms, if the value as changed

        }
    }, 250);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way here is to preload the json or load it once on`$dirty` and then the filter search will take care of the rest. This'll save you the extra http calls and its much faster with preloaded data. Memory will hurt, but its worth it.