# Need help to delay of search results in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, settimeout, angularjs-filter

I want to write a code that gives the results after some delay of user search instead of instantaneous result.
Can I do that using a filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular 1.3 introduces `debounce` options in `ng-model`, which does exactly what you need - delay the changes in the models.

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="userForm">
    <label>Name:
      <input type="text" name="userName"
             ng-model="user.name"
             ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" />
    </label>
    <button ng-click="userForm.userName.$rollbackViewValue(); user.name=''">Clear</button>
    <br />
  </form>
  <pre>user.name = <span ng-bind="user.name"></span></pre>
</div>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

For further information, take a loot at discussion here [How to put a delay on AngularJS instant search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304562/how-to-put-a-delay-on-angularjs-instant-search)