# Add Debounce/Throttle to AngularJS ng-repeat filter

Tags: angularjs, throttling, debouncing

How can I add Debounce/Throttle of 300ms to ng-repeat filter to increase performance as I need to filter a huge array of objects. Please find below sample code.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="q" />
<div ng-repeat="user in users | filter : q">
 {{user.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304562/how-to-put-a-delay-on-angularjs-instant-search

Comment: see the link that @TheSameSon  commented

Comment: hadiJz, I've wrote my answer before this comment. So you downvoted me to no purpose

Comment: @EkaterinaTokareva, i put answer that similar to one of answers from above link. but Jagajit down vote it. i just mention this. of course your answer learn me new thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write ng-model-options:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="q" ng-model-options="{debounce: 300}"/>
```